# Mercurial, как обновить ветку до состояния другой ветки?

Tags: mercurial, branch

Имеется две ветки: мастер и тест.
В мастере полностью product версия, а ветка тест используется для развёртывания на тестовом сервере и содержит много изменений от разработчиков. Так получилось, что тест начал очень сильно различаться от мастера и нужно сделать так, чтобы ветка тест стала полной копией ветки мастер с удалением всех новых изменений. Вопрос, как это  сделать? Закрывать ветку не вариант, так как она завязана на сборку на тесте.

Comment: А что значит "завязана"? На имя ветки? Нельзя ли закрыть ветку тест и переоткрыть новую именную ветку тест от мастера?

Comment: ветка закроется, разве её можно переоткрыть?

Comment: Можно. Это будет "restart branch". Не могу прогнозировать последствия, но новая ветка получает имя старой ветки.